# c++ find the occurance of number in array

Tags: c++, arrays

in an array of integers 0-100 can anyone write a function that will count the number of occurrences of each possible value then overwrite the original array?
(no this is not homework, its practice test, so i can study)

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello, @JessicaL. Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: void count_sort(int min, int max, int & A[], int items);

Comment: When you say "array of integers 0-100", do you mean an arbitrarily-sized array of `int`, in which each member of the array has value between 0 and 100 inclusive? Or do you mean an array of 100 `int`s, each of which may have any value?

Comment: What do you mean by "anyone"?  If I'm writing the program, I can certainly write such a function.  If I'm just given the program in compiled form, I can't write an arbitrary function, insert it in, and have it do anything.  It sounds like you're thinking of a class of people relative to a program and array, and I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: I think the questioner wants each number to be overwritten with it's frequency? Still not sure whether it's a range 0 to 100 or just a bunch of numbers, being between 0 and 100.

Comment: 100 int's like test scores i guess you can say, would you use an if statement and null?

Comment: @JessicaL: Can you give us some sample data: A before and after?

Answer (score 2):

```
void 
count_sort(int min, int max, int & A[], int items) {
```

Here is a little something to get you started. We know that any member of `A[]` can hold only a number from 0 through 100. We need a place to keep the counts of each number (i.e., 0 ... 100). Another array of our own, with a counter for each of the possible numbers, is a natural place for such a collection of counts:

```
int counts[101];                 // there are 101 numbers in 0 ... 100 inclusive
int i;                           // we'll use this an an index into the counts[ ] array
int j;                           // this we can use as an index into A[]
```

We can't forget to make all the members of the counts[] array be zero, otherwise all of our totals will be nonsense:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 101; i++ ) {    // so let's preset all of the counts to 0
  counts[i] = 0;
}
```

Now you can read the input array from top to bottom. When you take a number from the array, use it as the index into the counts[ ] array where you are keeping the running total of the numbers you find. So suppose you retrieve the number 35 from the input array:

```
i = next_input_array_number( );   // i will be 35 after this is executed
```

So now you have (in `i`) the next number; and you have a spot to count its occurrence: `counts[35]`. How are you now going to increment `counts[35]`?

And then keep on getting numbers from the input array, one by one, until you've seen all `items` of them. When you're finished with the input array -- i.e., after you've seen and counted all the numbers -- you are all finished and the counts[] array will hold the total times each number was seen in the input array.

What you have to do is figure out how to get numbers from the input array; that is, you have to substitute some code for "next_input_array_number();".

Please post the code you'll use to retrieve numbers from the input array.